# Force a new line character in query string

Tags: php, wordpress, newline, query-string

I've got a link that I'm using to add an entry into my Google calendar. I'm getting the data from database which is stored in a human readable format (it was initially captured from a text area), which typically is spread over more than one line, for example...

> Big day out at the zoo.
>       Bring sunscreen.

...and on my page I set it as a variable...

```
$event_info = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_info', TRUE);
```

The problem is when I create a query string it doesn't account for the new line characters (just showing the relevant part of the query string below)...

> &details=Big+day+out+at+the+zoo.Bring+sunscreen.

...and so when I view it in my Calendar it looks like this...

> Big day out at the zoo. Bring sunscreen.

...instead of on two lines.

I understand that I can use a new line character in the query string with %0D but I don't know how to get it into my query string. I'm guessing there is some PHP function for this purpose that will take my `$event_info` variable and add the new line characters, but I'm unsure.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try ..

```
$event_info = urlencode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_info', TRUE));
```